# Updates on wordpress are not applied even if I saved them

Tags: php, wordpress

This is like an open ended question. I have a wordpess website which use do online shopping. There are items. let say table lamps. They have different prices. I need to update prices time to time.  I have updated the prices on wordpress but it is not updated despite the fact that I have already saved the changes.Can you please tell any possible reasons for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a theme or plugin or both that is out of date. You should also check your console for errors. Try updating everything, then try updating the post again. Be sure to back up your site first.